# bypass Adobe PDF Printer "SaveFileAs" prompt

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe

i have a program that opens files, creates a PDF version by sending it to Adobe printer and saving the created PDF in a specified output folder. occassionally, when it creates the PDF, it throws a "Save PDF File As" dialog. since it does this for thousands of files, i don't think its an issue within the program. this dialog only appears for some files. can anyone tell me if its a setting for the Adobe printer or registry settings that would cause this?

i think this question has been asked on many forums but I have not been able to find a solution to this problem.

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can write a key to the [registry](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9/Acrobat9_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=Distiller_WinIntro.61.11.html).
Here is an example of the registry key for PDFing from WordPad.

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\PrinterJobControl**
Value Name: **C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe**
Type: **REG_SZ**
Value Data: **c:\MyPDFoutputFileName.pdf**

For [**Window 64-bit OS**](http://acrobatusers.com/forum/pdf-creation/changing-file-name-programmatically-when-printing-adobe-pdf) you have to use **splwow64.exe** as the program.
It is normally located in **C:\Windows**.

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\PrinterJobControl**
Value Name: **C:\Windows\splwow64.exe**
Type: **REG_SZ**
Value Data: **c:\MyPDFoutputFileName.pdf**

If it still does not work then the program name might be wrong. To see the program name, manually create a PDF from the program. Acrobat will store the program name in the registry under "LastPdfPortFolder -".

In my case it was:
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\PrinterJobControl**
Value Name: **LastPdfPortFolder - splwow64.exe**
Value Data: **D:\0000**

As you can see **splwow64.exe** was shown there, which made me google it and ultimately figured out that the Adobe Documentation was a little lacking.

I am using:
Acrobat 9
Windows 7 Pro 64-bit
Printing to "Adobe PDF" printer.

Comment: The solution works, the prompting dialog box suppressed now. But another issue pop up. The Adobe Printer isn't able to generate the PDF to the desired location. I posted the problem here. Appreciate if you shed some light on the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148716/adobe-pdf-printer-doesnt-creating-the-pdf-file