# compress pdf by c# and adobe printer

Tags: pdf, printing, compression, adobe

One of my friend scans a lot of pages of documents and saves them as a pdf. 
The size of the resulting pdf is 1GB, when I reprint this pdf using adobe pdf printer, the size of my file changes and is reduced to 80MB.

I set up Adobe Acrobat X Pro to open pdfs and Adobe Acrobat X Pro sets up a virtual pdf printer for me.

The image quality in the second pdf is very good and the most important thing is the difference in filesize.

Now how can I do this in a c# program? I want to write a piece of c# code to do this automatically.

I have about 500 pdf files and size of these files is very large and I want to reduce the size of them.

I need a c# code to get the file path and print that file using Adobe pdf printer and get a pdf file to me, or I want to be able to set a export path for the output pdf. I tested some dlls to do this.

For example iTextSharp or PDFSharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_32 or sharpPDF_2_0_Beta2_dll among many other things.

But these are not nice and working with them is not easy for me. I just want a method or class or a fast component to do these.

Please remember we wanna do this with Adobe Acrobat X Pro.

Thanks

Comment: can you show your codes ?

Comment: Use `pdfbeads`. With JBIG2 and JPEG2000, you won't get anything smaller.

Comment: if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0) MessageBox.Show("please choose your file");
                else
                {
                    Process p = new Process();
                    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
                    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        Verb = "print",                       
                        FileName = textBox1.Text,
                    };
                    p.Start();}
also i set adobe pdf as default printer my self.now how can i set adobe pdf output folder by my c# code?

Comment: maybe this is useful but not completely : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075104/bypass-adobe-pdf-printer-savefileas-prompt/17258605#17258605) @Gerhard Weiss