# Adobe pdf printer doesn't creating the pdf file

Tags: pdf, printing, registry, adobe, acrobat

I'm creating an add-in in [Revit 2017](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/export-the-sheet-to-pdf-and-suppress-the-dialog-to-save-the-file/m-p/7832805#M29266). The addin will export drawing sheets to PDF files. So, whenever  I try to export the sheet a dialog box appears to choose the location to save. I tried to turn off the Prompting programmatically by adding a key to the Windows registry (as described in [Adobe documentation page 15-16](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Distiller9APIReference.pdf)).

Now, the prompting got turned off and now I'm facing an issue. *The issue is the Adobe Printer got stuck while creating the pdf file*. See the below image: **The PDF creating progress bar seems frozen, I waited for more than 10 mins and it didn't create the pdf file**.

Can anybody provide any fix?
Appreciate any suggestion.

[image: PDF file doesn't get generate the progress seems frozen]

**Edit**
here's the code that I've written for this purpose. I hope this may help to identify the problem.

```
public static bool ExportSheetToPDF(Document doc, string path)
{
    using (Transaction tx = new Transaction(doc)
    {

        tx.Start("Exportint to PDF");         

        PrintManager pm = doc.PrintManager;
        pm.SelectNewPrintDriver("Adobe PDF");
        pm.Apply();
        pm.PrintRange = PrintRange.Current;
        pm.Apply();
        pm.CombinedFile = true;
        pm.Apply();
        pm.PrintToFile = true;
        pm.Apply();
        pm.PrintToFileName = path + @"\PDF\" + "abc.pdf";
        pm.Apply();
        SuppressAdobeDialogAndSaveFilePath(path + @"\PDF\" + "abc.pdf");

        pm.SubmitPrint();
        pm.Apply();
        tx.Commit();

    }
    return true;
}

// Add Registry Key to suppress the dialog box
public static void SuppressAdobeDialogAndSaveFilePath(string value)
{
    var valueName = @"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2017\Revit.exe";
    var reg = currentUser.OpenSubKey(key, true);
    var tempReg = reg.OpenSubKey(valueName);
    if (tempReg == null)
    {
        reg = reg.CreateSubKey(valueName);
    }
    reg.SetValue(valueName, value);
    reg.Close();
}
```

Comment: Try the exact same task without turning off prompting, does it work ? What prompts did you get ? My suspicion is that its doing something along the lines of 'File exists do you want to overwrite it?' and can't display the dialog because you've turned it off, so you should also check to see if the output file already exists.

Comment: There is no file there I checked already, the folder is empty. And yes, it works as it should without turning off prompting. But I need to turn off the prompting. Because I can't ask a user a thousand times to write the file name for 1000 files. I want to give the file name through code. Do you have any other suggestion @kenS ?

Comment: Sorry, no, that's the only reason I could think of for not prompting causing a difference.

Comment: Since this is Windows you might be able to use a combination of RedMon and Ghostscript isntead of Acrobat Distiller. If you can export to PostScript (or PCL or XPS) then you could skip the necessity for RedMon and printing, just have Ghostscript consume the exported format and create a PDF from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have explained how you can achieve this by overriding the registry key for Revit.exe process that Adobe uses to generate the next print.

http://archi-lab.net/printing-pdfs-from-revit-why-is-it-so-hard/

Please remember that you still have to print via Revit PrintManager, but then you can set the registry keys before every print to control where the files get saved.