# How can I print to adobe acrobat printer (pdf) in Delphi silently

Tags: delphi, pdf, printing, adobe, acrobat

When I choose Adobe acrobat pdf printer and then want to print to it (create a pdf file) it ask me the putput filenam and after the printing Adobe acrobat opens the output pdf file.

I want to send filename to it myself (and It does't ask me it) and after printing it does't open the output file. I want that these operations done silently. I am using Delphi and Quickreport.

Comment: I do "silent PDF printing" using Microsoft Print to PDF. You can easily find out how to do that (well known). Have you tried the same approach with your Adobe printer?

Comment: thanks. can you send the codes for it. i use quickreport and i can't find getprinter and setprinter for it. i use below codes but it doesn't work correctly.   Printer.PrinterIndex:=Printer.Printers.IndexOf('Microsoft Print to PDF');
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DeviceMode);
  Printer.SetPrinter(Device, Driver, 'D:\Test.pdf', 0);
  qreport1.Print;

Comment: You need only to include the `Printers` unit to your `uses` clause (the `implementation` one will be sufficient).

Comment: FYI. Please note that the Microsoft Print to PDF is very very space inefficient. It makes large PDFs because it doesn't compress much. If using it for PDF for mail or archive you might want to choose a pdf printer which does a better job (or at least check Microsoft Print to PDF doesn't produce too large of a PDF for the job you use it for).

Comment: @KJ Yes there is a "Adobe PDF" printer. It's used for printing from *other* programs to a PDF. It's not about sending a pdf to a printer but to generate a pdf from Delphi and Quickreport https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/print-to-pdf.html

Comment: Very thanks. How can I change the properties of "adobe pdf" printer?(Assign file name like what said in : "https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169728/10802527"  by programming in Delphi ( not manually)

Comment: @Ham I tried the SetPrinter method with an Output filename in Delphi. It did create a pdf file but somehow seems to be corrupt. If you are on Windows 64 bit, and you are sure it's Adobe PDF you are dealing with, you can also create a (temporary) registry entry, print normally to "Adobe PDF" without prompt, and delete that registry entry. You can look at the answer here how it's done. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595887/1037511 If that works for you, you can mark this question a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I've used **Bullzip PDF Printer** in the past and been very impressed. Simply install it and then select is as the printer. Check the file sizes against **Microsoft Print to PDF** to see if they are better. And you'd need to check if it has the "silent" option you're after.